# An equivalent expression for an inequality

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ as a row vector and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is PSD matrix. Let:  $w \triangleq \mathbf{v}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}^{H}$. Can we write the following inequality based on $w$,

$$\text{Tr}(\mathbf{A}) \leq K, $$

where $K \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Comment: Nothing in your problem rules out the possibility that $A=0$ and so $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=0$.

Comment: Even a positive definite matrix wouldn't have a guaranteed lower bound for the trace.  Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Sorry, that was typo.

Comment: Ah, OK.  But still: don't diagonal matrices show that there's no upper bound for the trace either?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: this is part of an optimization problem and $A$ is its variable.